# Startup Disk Creator Uncaught Exception Error

Tags: usb-creator

When creating a boot-able USB or LiveUSB with Startup Disk creator in Ubuntu 12.04, the following error message appears:

```
Installation Failed
An uncaught exception was raised: Invalid version string 'GNU/LINUX'
```

What does this mean? Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Try running the Startup Disk Creator like so: usb-creator --allow-system-internal Be sure to select your USB key from the drive list, and not your system drive. *This seems to be a [documented bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/722019).*

Comment: If you start a terminal with `Ctl-Alt-T` what is the output of the `lsb_release -a` command?

Comment: It is quite long, it starts with this `LSB Version: core-2.0-ia32:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-ia32:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-ia32:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:cxx-3.0-ia32:cxx- ...` and ends with `Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 11.04
Release: 11.04
Codename: natty`

Comment: Were you trying to make a Ubuntu starup disk, or another OS (GNU/LINUX)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, this is not the documented bug mentioned by @SirCharlo.  In fact, it's not really a bug at all.  Startup Disk Creator is designed to only make Ubuntu startup disks. If you read the description of the program, it does actually say this, as I found out after the fact.

In my case, I was trying to make a Debian startup disk, and it has an OS Version labled "Debian GNU/Linux...", and therefore the app will not use it to make the disk.  Making a Ubuntu disk works perfectly.

It would be nice if it gave a better error message, but the behavior is evidently by design.

Comment: I confirm this, I had exactly the same error (trying to create Debian Jessie startup disk). The message is really misleading.

Comment: I use tuxboot or UNetbootin now to create USB disks.  Worked fine for Debian Jessie, which I tried out today (and which makes me appreciate how easy Ubuntu is!).